# PHP 7 herencia entre clases Persona y Trabajador, la clase hija no puede leer a los metodos de la padre

Tags: php, poo, php7, herencia

**Clase Padre** (`Persona.php`)

```
<?php 

    class Persona{

        public $nombre;
        public $apellidos;
        public $edad;
        public $pais;


        function __construct($nombre,$apellidos,$edad,$pais){
            $this->nombre = $nombre;
            $this->apellidos = $apellidos;
            $this->edad = $edad;
            $this->pais = $pais;

        }


        public function print(){

            echo "Nombre = " . $this->nombre;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Apellidos = " . $this->apellidos;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Edad = ".$this->edad;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Pais = ".$this->pais;
            echo "<br>";


        }


    }


 ?>
```

**Clase Hija** (`Trabajador.php`)

```
<?php 


    class Trabajador extends Persona{

        public $profesion;


        public function print($nombre,$apellidos,$edad,$pais,$profesion){
            parent::__construct($nombre,$apellidos,$edad,$pais);
            $this->profesion = $profesion;
        }

        public function print(){
            parent::print();
            echo "Profesion: ". $this->profesion;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }

 ?>
```

Como se ve en la **clase hija** extiendo de `Persona.php`  los **atributos** y luego añado el propio de la clase, en este caso `$this->profesion`. 
Luego en mi funcion `print(){}` llamo al **print padre** y luego lo aumento con el **echo de la nueva propiedad**

**Clase main** (`main.php`)

```
<?php 

    include_once 'Coche.php';
    include_once 'Persona.php';
    include_once 'Trabajador.php';



    echo "<h1>MAIN CLASSS</h1>";
    echo "<br>";




    $trabajador = new Trabajador('Luis','Gutierrez Franco',18, 'España','Programador Web Junior');

    $trabajador->print();

 ?>
```

**El error es el siguiente:**

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Trabajador::print()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede tener dos métodos con el mismo nombre en la misma clase.

En el ejemplo que pones, tienes declarado dos veces `print`.

```
class Trabajador extends Persona {
    public $profesion;

    public function print($nombre,$apellidos,$edad,$pais,$profesion) {
        //          ^^^^^
        parent::__construct($nombre,$apellidos,$edad,$pais);
        $this->profesion = $profesion;
    }

    public function print() {
        //          ^^^^^
        parent::print();
        echo "Profesion: ". $this->profesion;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Cambiando el nombre a una de ellas debería funcionar.

Comment: Eso era, muchas gracias !.